# where to get the record id when calling backbone.js destroy

Tags: backbone.js, destroy

I have some test code that i'm just trying to use to figure out backbone.js.  when i call destroy on a model object backbone makes a DELETE request to my rest service.  but, i can't see any ID indicating which record is being deleted in the request data, the querystring, body or anywhere.

my model has an id property and i've assigned it a value of 1.  is there anything else that i have to do to make sure the id gets passed through the server?  or is there some other way that i'm supposed to detect what record is being deleted?

Edit - Here's the relevant code:

```
var AccountModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    url: 'Account/Update',
    id: null,
    username: ''
});

var accountM = new AccountModel({id: 1, username: 'test'});

accountM.destroy();
```

When I look at the debugger I see the AJAX request is made, it just looks like this:

```
Request URL:http://localhost/probli/Account/Update
Request Method:DELETE
Status Code:200 OK
```

There doens't seem to be an ID or anything and there's no post data.  Am I doing anything wrong?  Thanks.

Comment: could you share your test code please?

Comment: i just edited the post to add code.  thanks for looking!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You should set the [urlRoot](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Model-urlRoot) attribute of your model then let Backbone handle constructing the `DELETE` url:

```
var AccountModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot: 'Account/Update',
    id: null,
    username: ''
});
```

This will cause the following request when `accountM.destroy()` is called:

```
Request URL:http://localhost/probli/Account/Update/1
Request Method:DELETE
Status Code:200 OK
```

Comment: How does the null id turn into 1?

Comment: @lulalala when creating a new instance with this line `new AccountModel({id: 1, username: 'test'});`

Comment: I'd also add that you *only* need urlRoot. If you have both url and urlRoot, you may experience this issue, getting rid of url should clear it up.

Answer (score 1):

Backbone.sync will send the destroy back as a simple request with the ID in the url. For example:

`DELETE http://example.com/foos/1`

This is the HTTP delete for a `Foo` with an id of `1`.

In MVC web servers like Rails, ASP.NET MVC, and even Sinatra and other simple servers, this will be a parameter that comes through to your server.

For example, in Sinatra:

```
delete "/foos/:id" do

  id = params[:id] # the id from the url/route

  foo = Foos.find(id) # get the foo
  foo.destroy
  return {}.to_json
end
```

As you can see, I defined a parameter in the route, called `:id` and my code was able to access it via the `params` data. I then found the `Foo` in question, destroyed it, and returned an empty JSON result - which is required by Backbone, even during a destroy.

Hope that helps.

Comment: thanks for the reply.  is there somewhere in the backbone javascript that you specify where the id will be added to the url?  I just posted some sample code and looking at the dubugger i can see the request being made but there's no id.  thanks.

Comment: Any update to this. I'm having the same issue. DELETE request is sent but `id` is not sent in the URL. I've checked the model does exist in the collection with a valid id